# Why is the value of my variable always zero?

Tags: batch-file, colors

I am trying to change the colors of the command prompt with two `choice` commands. I know that `choice` sets the error level, but when I select any number, only 0 is returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
    choice /c 0123456789abcdef /D 0 /t 25 /n /M "Choose background color:         0:Black 1:Blue 2:Green 3:Aqua 4:Red 5:Purple 6:Yellow 7:White 8:Gray         9:Light Blue A:Light Green B:Light Aqua C:Light Red D:Light Purple         E:Light Yellow F:Bright White"
    if errorlevel 16 set back=f
    if errorlevel 15 set back=e
    if errorlevel 14 set back=d
    if errorlevel 13 set back=c
    if errorlevel 12 set back=b
    if errorlevel 11 set back=a
    if errorlevel 10 set back=9
    if errorlevel 9 set back=8
    if errorlevel 8 set back=7
    if errorlevel 7 set back=6
    if errorlevel 6 set back=5
    if errorlevel 5 set back=4
    if errorlevel 4 set back=3
    if errorlevel 3 set back=2
    if errorlevel 2 set back=1
    if errorlevel 1 set back=0
    echo %back%
    choice /c 0123456789abcdef /D 7 /t 25 /n /M "Choose text color: 0:Black         1:Blue 2:Green 3:Aqua 4:Red 5:Purple 6:Yellow 7:White 8:Gray 9:Light         Blue A:Light Green B:Light Aqua C:Light Red D:Light Purple E:Light         Yellow F:Bright White"
    if errorlevel 16 set text=f
    if errorlevel 15 set text=e
    if errorlevel 14 set text=d
    if errorlevel 13 set text=c
    if errorlevel 12 set text=b
    if errorlevel 11 set text=a
    if errorlevel 10 set text=9
    if errorlevel 9 set text=8
    if errorlevel 8 set text=7
    if errorlevel 7 set text=6
    if errorlevel 6 set text=5
    if errorlevel 5 set text=4
    if errorlevel 4 set text=3
    if errorlevel 3 set text=2
    if errorlevel 2 set text=1
    if errorlevel 1 set text=0
    echo %text%

    color %back%%text%
```

Answer (score 0):

This one's subtle, and it's caused by a combination of things. You have two ways of accessing the `%errorlevel%` variable: with `%`s and without.

While your `if errorlevel` syntax is valid, it means "if `%errorlevel%`is ___ *or higher*," so because you aren't using `else`s with your `if`s, the script just keeps on moving down the line and finding true statements, eventually setting both variables to 0 because **every single one of those `if` statements will always evaluate to true.**

If you want to keep the syntax you're using, you need to add parentheses and put the `else` on the same line as the `)`, like this:

```
if errorlevel 16 (
    set back=f
) else if errorlevel 15 (
    set back=e
) else if errorlevel 14 (
    set back=d
) else if errorlevel 13 (
    set back=c
)
```

The other way is to use the normal form of the `%errorlevel%` variable and treat  like a regular variable (the benefit of this is that you don't have to write the list backwards for this).

```
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" set text=0
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" set text=1
if "%errorlevel%"=="3" set text=2
if "%errorlevel%"=="4" set text=3
```

Comment: @Magoo - better?

Comment: Umm  - it's still quite different from the original, as I've pointed out in my response...

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you've posted suffers from there being no description of what "doesn't work".

As posted, you would receive error messages because the `/m` string may not be extended over more than one line. That *may* have been your problem as that will not generate a syntax-error message.

OR it may have been the execution of the `errorlevel` tree that might have given you your problem.

Sadly, the Dark One's edit has corrected the first of these problems.

My approach (admittedly it doesn't make the same presentation) would be:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

CALL :hue back 0 25 "Choose background"
CALL :hue text 7 25 "Choose text"
COLOR %back%%text%
ECHO %back%%text%
PAUSE
GOTO :eof

:: Parameters are : %1=varname, %2=default, %3=timeout, %4=prompt

:hue
cls
FOR %%a IN (0:Black 
    1:Blue 2:Green 3:Aqua 4:Red 5:Purple 6:Yellow 7:White 8:Gray 
    "9:Light Blue" "A:Light Green" "B:Light Aqua"
    "C:Light Red" "D:Light Purple" "E:Light Yellow" "F:Bright White") DO (
  ECHO %%~a
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%c IN ("%%~a") DO (
   IF %%c==%2 SET "%1=%%d"
  )
)

choice /c 0123456789abcdef /D %2 /t %3 /n /M "%~4 [!%1!] "
SET "%1= 0123456789abcdef"
SET "%1=!%1:~%errorlevel%,1!"

GOTO :eof
```

That is, to call the routine `:hue` with the parameters as described.

`:hue` works by having `%%a` iterate through the strings in parentheses and `echo`ing them in turn to the screen. The strings are separated by spaces, so where a space is required in the name, the string as required is quoted. the `~` in the `echo` removes the enclosing quotes.

the `for..%%c..` takes each string in turn from the list, removes any enclosing quotes and then applies quotes to the result. the `for /f` tokenises this resultant string, placing the part before the colon (the "delims" character) into `%%c` and that after into `%%d`. When `%%c` matches `%2` (the second parameter provided to `:hue`), then `%1` (the variablename supplied) will be set to `%%d` which contains the name from the string in `%%a`.

Then we execute the `choice` with the default, timeout and message from %2..%4 (same `~` to remove quotes...) and adds in the name by extracting the value of the variable `%`.

Then `set` the variable to a string containing all of the letters with a leading space, and then again to the substring of length 1 starting from the `errorlevel`th position OF the variable `%1` (which starts at "character 0" which is the reason for the leading space)

Yeah - not for beginners, but I'd got it worked out, so I posted it in case someone finds it useful.